# Render Multiple Sections from Sprite Sheet Simultaneously in Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, sprite, sprite-sheet

EDITED: The following renders sprite sheet images; now I need to give different behavior to each entity: key movement to boy, random animation to owl. I can do this with isolated images, but where/how to include behavior for each drawImage instance? Thanks.

```
<script>
var width = 50,
        height = 50,
        frames = 3,

        currentFrame = 0,

        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        image = new Image();
        image.src = "sprites.png"

        var draw = function(){
                ctx.clearRect(200, 400, width, height); //boy
                ctx.clearRect(150, 300, width, height); //owl
                ctx.clearRect(50, 400, width, height); //goat

                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, height * currentFrame, width, height, 200,400, width, height); //boy

                ctx.drawImage(image, 50, 50 * 2, width, height, 150, 300, width, height); //owl

                ctx.drawImage(image, 150, 50 * currentFrame, width, height, 50, 400, width, height); //goat

                ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 50 * 3, width, height, 150, 400, width, height); //bush


                if (currentFrame == frames) {
                  currentFrame = 0;
                } else {
                  currentFrame++;
                }
        }

        setInterval(draw, 550);
```

Comment: Rtfm.  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()

Comment: Thanks—tfm is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function to get the tile position and size based on the spritesheet layout. This makes these sort of things easier to handle. Provide index [0, 15] and you'll get back an object with the tile's position:

```
function getTile(index) {

    var row = (index / 4)|0,   // line
        col = index % 4,       // column
        w = 50,                // tile width and height
        h = 50;

    return {
        x: col * w,
        y: row * h,
        w: w,
        h: h
    }
}
```

The `drawImage()` method works this way (for this overload):

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh,  dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

where s* are the *source* coordinates in your spritesheet, and d* is destination position and size for the clipped region you get from the s* coordinates.

So here you could do:

```
var width = 50,
    height = 50,
    frames = 16,
    currentFrame = 0,
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
    setInterval(draw, 400);  // start when image has finished loading
}
image.src = "sprites.png"

function draw(){

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    var tile = getTile(currentFrame);        
    ctx.drawImage(image, tile.x, tile.y, tile.w, tile.h, 0, 0, width, height); 

    currentFrame++;

    if (currentFrame === frames) {
      currentFrame = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Epistemex, revised code above—images render now. From your response I'm guessing that I should create tile variables for each entity (boy, owl, etc.) in order to give behavior to sprites? Thanks.

Comment: @p1nesap you could do that, you could expand the getTile function to support specific metrics for the spritesheet (ie. tile width and height, number of columns etc.). Hope this helps!

Comment: By behavior I mean assign arrow key movement to "boy", etc. Where/how do I start to do this, and how to create index array based on spreadsheet if that's what I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: @p1nesap that's a bit out of scope for this question. You can open a new question for these specific things. If the answer solved the problem in this question please consider to accept the answer.